# How can we run a script in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm new to programming and am having difficulty running a script in Julia. I will try to be as detailed as possible so that it will be easier to help me. I am using VS code as my code editor and have made a folder on my desktop called: **FirstProgram**. In this folder I have created a file called: **HelloWorld.jl**. This file has the following code in it:

```
println("Hello World")
```

So in order to run this code, I opened the julia terminal in VS code and typed

```
include("HelloWorld.jl")
```

When I did this, nothing happened.

Next I tried to run this code in the julia repl outside of VS code by typing:

```
include("HelloWorld.jl")
```

When I did this, I was met with the following error:

```
julia> include("HelloWorld.jl")

ERROR: could not open file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\HelloWorld.jl
Stacktrace:
 [1] include at .\boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [3] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [4] include(::String) at .\client.jl:403
 [5] top-level scope at none:0

julia>
```

After doing more research, I tried running this code in command prompt with julia and was met with the same error as above.

Lastly, I tried the code runner extension in VS code. This time I was not met with errors however nothing would output.

Can anyone explain how to run a julia script and how I can avoid the above errors? Moreover, can someone explain how to use the code runner extension successfully? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running Julia from the same folder/directory your file is in? The error suggests your current directory is the Julia appdata directory, which is an odd place to be.

Comment: Hi lurker, I downloaded Julia into the appdata folder because a tutorial told me to do so. However, if this is a problem, can you guide me into moving the folder into the correct place? Moreover, i'm assuming this also means that all of my projects must be stored in a specific folder? Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to run `pwd()` in the Julia terminal. If the directory it returns does not match the directory in which you have your file then either use the `cd` function to change it or in `include` specify a full path to the file you want to include.

Comment: Hi, I checked the directory and my file is there however it still does not open. I am met with the same lengthy error shown above. What should I do to fix this file problem you mentioned.

Comment: Just to clarify this is what I inputted:
 include("C:\\Users\\Gurbaz\\Desktop\\FirstProgram")

Comment: I'm a little confused. In your question, you mentioned that you entered, `include("HelloWorld.jl")` and the error said it could not open `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1\HelloWorld.jl`. This path indicates to me that your current directory was `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Julia-1.1.1` when you ran `julia` and did the `include`. But your last comment says you entered `include("C:\\Users\\Gurbaz\\Desktop\\FirstProgram")`. You only need to store your programs in a folder you have permission to access, then run `julia` while you're in that folder, or point julia to that folder.

Comment: Hi, I meant to replace Gurbaz with User. Sorry for the confusion. Can you explain how I can point Julia to a folder. Thanks

Comment: In VS Code, open a new terminal and enter the command "julia". This should open the REPL for Julia. Look at the command prompt for the terminal above Julia. This is the directory you are in. to list files, enter ;ls at the julia prompt. To change directories, enter ;cd <subdir> at the julia prompt. The ; gets you to a shell command prompt in Julia's REPL.